# What is the maximum possible size of microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.id field

Tags: push-notification, exchangewebservices

I need to store the id, in my sql db, of the folder while subscribing for notifications with ews. So wanted to know how the [id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.id(v=exchg.80).aspx) of the folders are generated and what could be the maximum possible character length of this field.
If it's not fixed length for all the folders, is it fixed for Inbox folder? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_CommonIdentifiers

> > If you are going to store the item ID in a database to retrieve later, we recommend that the field size be 512 bytes, so that it’s large enough to hold the GUID.